# How to take some percentage of values from a list which has been sorted in descending order in python?

Tags: python, list

I have the below list sorted in descending order.
List is:

```
[717.1573237876664, 182.7371943521783, 159.83445384690813, 51.76429530389303, 45.6779696561034, 30.617835033786744, 28.400451713817905, 25.784283394118074, 19.37917065]
```

And I have to take some percentage of values from this list say 80% and that must be in order .eg.

```
Length of the List: 9
then 80% of 9 = 7.2
```

Take 7 values from the List in sorted order that is considered

```
[717.1573237876664, 182.7371943521783, 159.83445384690813, 51.76429530389303, 45.6779696561034, 30.617835033786744, 28.400451713817905].
```

I am not getting how to write the code for it.

Comment: `my_list[:int(len(my_list) * 0.8)]`?

Comment: Then How would I get the values in order?

Comment: If it was already sorted, the first 7 elements will also be in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use list slicing:

```
mylist = [717.1573237876664, 182.7371943521783, 159.83445384690813, 51.76429530389303, 45.6779696561034, 30.617835033786744, 28.400451713817905, 25.784283394118074, 19.37917065]
percent = 80
print(mylist[:int(len(mylist) * percent / 100)])
# [717.1573237876664, 182.7371943521783, 159.83445384690813, 51.76429530389303, 45.6779696561034, 30.617835033786744, 28.400451713817905]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
new_list = old_list[:int(len(old_list)*0.8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, calculate the number of elements you need -

```
elements = int(len(x) * (percent/100)) # x here is your list and len(x) is the length of your list
```

Next, splice the old list -

```
new_list = x[:elements+1]
```

Since your own list is sorter already, we don't need to sort again. In case you do need to sort the list, see [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

Also, see how [slicing](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html) works.